# How do I solve a binomial theorem with a factor inserted in

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-theorem

I have a given formula which is very similar to the Binomial Formula

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{n} \binom{n}{k} z^k (1-z)^{n-k} = z$$

I have to prove that the above statement is true. As of right now I could only show that if $\frac{k}{n}$ were not there the sum would get the value 1 which I can only use to prove that $\frac{k}{n} \sim z$. Anyone know of any way to help me with this. I have also tried solving with induction but I get stuck on

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k} z^k (1-z)^{n+1-k} = z$$

Comment: Have you tried simplifying $\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: I have been trying multiple ways on how to simplify them but no single way gets me closer to a solution @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: If $k=0$, $\frac{k}{n}{n \choose k}=0$, so the corresponding term can be removed. If $k \ge 1$, $$\frac{k}{n}{n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k-1}.$$ Then you make a change of index $\ell := k-1$ in the sum...

Comment: If I understood you correctly (which I probably didn't since I don't learn in english) then I would be left with $$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} z^k (1-z)^{n-k} = z$$ which doesnt help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}z^k(1-z)^{n-k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}z^k(1-z)^{n-k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}z^{k+1}(1-z)^{n-1-k}\tag{3}\\
> &=z(z+(1-z))^{n-1}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=z}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we skip the index with $k=0$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$
- In (3) we shift the index $k$ by one and start with $k=0$. This is compensated by substituting each occurrence of $k$ with $k+1$.
- In (4) we factor out $z$ and apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we make a final simplification.

Comment: thank you for the answer. What I dont understand is how after making $n$ into $n-1$ and $k=0$ a $z$ appeared as a coefficient

Comment: I saw your edit now, but wouldnt that also make a $k+1$ out of $k$ in $(1-z)^{n-1-k}$ making point (4) $= z(z+(1-z))^n = z$?

Comment: @Biohazard: Fine. I see you got the point. :-)

Comment: you have been more than helpful and I cannot thank you enough. for some reason our prof. doesn't even have the binomial identity anywhere in the script and also any other of the neat tricks you used with shifting the index. Stuff I had never seen until now. Again thank you very much.

Comment: @Biohazard: You're welcome.

Comment: Something irks me still about step (3). If I follow just that I get \begin{align*}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}z^{k+1}(1-z)^{n-1-k+1}\tag{3}\\
&=z\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}z^{k}(1-z)^{n-k}\tag{3.5}\\
&=z(z+(1-z))^{n-1}\tag{4}\\
&=z\tag{5}
\end{align*}

And so for point (3.5) I cannot use the binomial theorem as far as I know since I need to have it in a form similiar to $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k}{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k y^{n-k}$ and in this case it has been altered in a way that the $n$ in the binomial is not the same as the $n$ present in the power of $y$.

Comment: @Biohazard: Note, in step (3) we have $(1-z)^{n-(k+1)}=(1-z)^{n-1-k}$.

Comment: Ohhhh, so we don't alter the $n$ because of the index change. Okay that is very good to know.